# Correct filter size with kernel size

Tags: conv-neural-network

I found a conv tutorial https://burakhimmetoglu.com/2017/08/22/time-series-classification-with-tensorflow. Is the filters size 72 not logic for kernel size 2? Because the possibility of kernel is just 15. We don't need to have additional 57 same filter right?

```
tf.layers.conv1d( filters=72, kernel_size=2 )
```

If the kernel is 2, then the max possibility of kernel are 
`00
01

00
11

01
11

11
11

10
00

11
00

11
10

10
01

01
10`

Comment: 72 is the number of filters to apply kernel, size of 2.

Comment: If the kernel is 2, then the max possibility of kernel are 
`00
01

00
11

01
11

11
11

10
00

11
00

11
10

10
01

01
10`